# DataTables YajraBox Laravel extension with Eloquent Query String Filtering

Tags: php, jquery, datatables, laravel-5.4

im newbie Laravel, im trying to create a data table with [YajraBox](https://github.com/yajra/laravel-datatables-demo/blob/master/app/Http/Controllers/EloquentController.php) extension.

Im stuck on ajax controller:

```
public function indexData(LotFilters $filters)
    {
       $lots  = Lot::filter($filters)->get();

        return Datatables::of($lots)->make(true);
    }
```

This is my route:

```
Route::get('data', 'LotController@indexData');
```

When i go: `http://127.0.0.1:8000/data` it gives me an error:

> Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate
>   140673944 bytes)

It think i need to set up a pagination, but i didn't find a example how to do it, maybe you guys can help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually i find a solution just now. i just need to remove `->get();` from the end.

Answer (score 2):

you are making get request which may cause this error. Try to make a post request.